# Trying to use EditorFor with an ICollection<string> in an ASP.NET MVC3 View?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, editorfor

I'm trying to display a class object in a `Create` view, where a property is an `ICollection<string>`.

For example...

```
namespace StackOverflow.Entities
{
    public class Question
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        ....
        public ICollection<string> Tags { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and if the view was like a StackOverflow 'ask a question' page, where the `Tags` html element is a single `input box` ..  I'm not sure how I could do that in an ASP.NET MVC3 view?

Any ideas?

I tried using `EditorFor` but nothing was displayed in the browser, because it's not sure how to render a collection of strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start by decorating your view model with the [`[UIHint]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [UIHint("tags")]
    public ICollection<string> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

and then in the main view:

```
@model StackOverflow.Entities.Question
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Tags)
```

and then you could write a custom editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/tags.cshtml`):

```
@model ICollection<string>
@Html.TextBox("", string.Join(",", Model))
```

or if you don't like decorating, you could also specify the editor template to be used for the given property directly in the view:

```
@model StackOverflow.Entities.Question
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Tags, "tags")
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/tags.cshtml`?

Comment: @MystereMan, yes it should. Thanks for noticing it.

Comment: How can I preserve the collection data when it posts back? I tried adding a `foreach` in my editor template with `HiddenFor`s but didn't seem to work :(