# How should I program this controllers ActionResult method with this simple Create View for my ASP.NET MVC3 view?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, controller

I'm not sure if I should use a `FormsCollection` or something else, with this basic `Create` view.

(note: I'm using a [custom editor template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635555/trying-to-use-editorfor-with-an-icollectionstring-in-an-asp-net-mvc3-view) for the Tags `ICollection<string>`)

#### Model

```
public class Question
{
    [Required, StringLength(100)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

#### View

```
@model AWing.Core.Entities.Product

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Question</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tags)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tags, "tags")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tags)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create a new product" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

#### Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormsCollection formsCollection)
{
  ... ????
}
```

or something else?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(... ??? ...)
{
  .... ????
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have a strongly typed View, you can have your `[HttpPost]` method take that same type as the variable, e.g.:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Product model)  
{  
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // add new product
        .... ????
    } 
}
```

The `DefaultModelBinder` will take the values returned, and plug them into your strongly typed model.  Viola!

As long as the model for your template for your tags collection is of type `string`, MVC will iterate through the collection, so that it can be bound (though you may have to change from `ICollection` to List).

**UPDATE**

As we discussed in the comments, rather than creating one textbox per tag, create a separate ViewModel which has all of your other Product properties.

Instead of using `List<string> Tags` in your ViewModel, create this property:

```
public string TagCollection { get; set; }
```

In your view, have a textbox for `TagCollection`. Then, in your Create action, you can parse the TagCollection string into your list of tags.

Comment: As long as the model for your template for your tags collection is of type string, MVC will iterate through the collection, so that it can be bound (though you may have to change from ICollection to List).

Comment: what happens if the tags collection is not of List<string> .. but .. say .. i donno .. List<Tag> ?

Comment: Also, changing the tags collection to an `IList<string>` or `List<string>` also doesn't work -> it creates a single string with all the content in it. So if i enter the following into the textbox: `abc 1234 asp.net-mvc3` it will store that as one string in the collection ... not 3 separate strings.

Comment: Name the elements as listname[0] listname[1] and the DefaultModelBinder will detect it's a collection and wire up to your List<>

Comment: @DaveHogan So this means I would need 1 textbox per tag? If yes, then do I need a custom model binder to handle a single text box for ALL tags, just like the tags textbox for a StackOverflow question?

Comment: Rather than creating one textbox per tag, I would create a separate ViewModel which has all of your other Product properties, and instead of List<string> Tags, has this property: `public string TagCollection { get; set; }`, and have a textbox for TagCollection.  Then, in your Create action, you can parse the TagCollection string into your list of tags.

Comment: @counsellorben awesome! create a proper answer and i'll tick it :)